# install python 2 and 3 in notebook , python 3 kernel error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed anaconda3 , so i have already a notebook for python 3 ,
i wanted to have python 2 with the 3 in the notebook , so i tried many solutions in stackoverflow , finally it worked , but the strange thing is python3 notebook is not working it give me in the top right corner **kernel error** when i click it it bring up an error message ,
commands i used to have python 2 notebook with python3 :-

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 ipykernel
```

it didnt work 
then :

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    # On Windows, remove the word 'source'
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

it worked , then i removed py36 and py27 as i thought they are usless now , then the probelm showed up ,

thank you in advance .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the commands you used to install a Python2 Kernel. Ideally, you'd use a separate conda env for each kernel

Comment: done , but please give me chance to edit , why people are rushing to give negative to the question !!!

Comment: @cricket_007 is it good now ?

Comment: `py36 and py27` are what ipython need to run! Why did you delete them?? No wonder the error says "No file exists"

Comment: because when i made them nothing happen , then when i used my second solution and made **ipykernel_py2** i thought now i have python 3 the default and python 2 ! and thanks brother for helping @cricket_007

Comment: is there a solution for this ?

Comment: so if i made them agien it will work ? @cricket_007

Comment: Go ahead, try it and make them again. Both are needed

Comment: @cricket_007 brother it worked , please write your answer ,in separate cell so i can close the subject and make your answer the right one :) and thank you ,,

Comment: another  question , now i have `py36 and py27 and ipykernel_py2` now when i want to add libraries for notebook python 2 or notebook python 3 , where i add them ? @cricket_007

Comment: You must activate each conda environment individually and use `conda` or `pip` like any other way you'd install python packages.

Comment: thank you @cricket_007 all good to you :)